# How LTE module UE got an IP address?

Tags: android, cellular-network, lte

I recently works on a LTE project by using Qualcomm MSM 9x7 manufactued by Quctel. When the module dial in, the module will be assigned an IP address by ISP. I heard from LTE expert that LTE is based on IP protocol, so my question is that how does the module got the IP address? Is that by dhcp mechanism or other LTE based IP address assignment protocol?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is typically how the UE address is assigned (steps 4-8). Alternatively, it can also be assigned statically, where the P-GW would query the HSS for the static ip associated with the subscriber, but the IP address would be pushed down to the UE in the same fashion. For more info [this](https://www.netmanias.com/en/?m=view&id=techdocs&no=7246) is a good doc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

LTE uses IP-based network architecture, i.e. it sends and receives data in form of packets, even for voice calls.
Hence, the IP is assigned when the user registers on the network.

[Reference from 3GPP-LTE overview](http://www.3gpp.org/technologies/keywords-acronyms/98-lte):
"The Evolved Packet System (EPS) is purely IP based. Both real time services and datacom services will be carried by the IP protocol. The IP address is allocated when the mobile is switched on and released when switched off."

Answer (score 0):

The LTE device gets the IP address from the PDN-GW (Packet Data Network Gateway) as you can see from the answer posted by @hiandbaii.